# M1 Macbook Air - is Boot Camp Ubuntu possible?

Tags: ubuntu, mac, installation, multi-boot, arm

I have been using Ubuntu on a VM on my M1 and I quite enjoy it so I have been thinking about running it natively.

I have seen many videos and I know how to but I have a few general questions.

1. I know that I can revert to MacOS using the command `bpuilt -n` however, will all my data and apps still be there?
2. How does one revert to Ubuntu after reverting to MacOS, will I have to repeat the entire installation process?
3. Are there any major flaws with M1 ubuntu as if now? I.e. Does wifi, usb, and bluetooth work?

I would really appreciate if someone who has installed Ubuntu on an M1 answered, and also told me about their experience, as well as answering my questions. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

M1 Macs don't support Boot Camp-style installations at all.

They are ARM chipsets, not Intel, so no regular Windows or nix build would be able to run on it anyway.
If you have a VM structure that works [lots of them don't] then stick to it.